# Линейное движение точки под углом: отскок

Tags: анимация, алгоритм, геометрия

Приветствую.

В общих чертах, пишу алгоритм перемещения точки в пределах прямоугольника, скажем 600 x 400. Точка имеет такие свойства:

- текущие координаты `X` и `Y`, при чем, `X` = [0,600]; `Y` = [0,400] (просто перемещаю div по relative-контейнеру)
- кинетический заряд `A` (длина шага за 1 такт — гипотенуза)
- угол `Angle` (град.)

Сначала долго ломал голову насчет самого передвижения точки в направлении, указанном углом `Angle`. Когда обнаружил решение, стало стыдно. Вот оно:

```
X = X + A * cos(Angle * PI / 180);
Y = Y + A * sin(Angle * PI / 180);
```

С этим все нормально:

- если `Angle` = 0, то точка движется вправо по OX,
- если `Angle` = 180, то влево,
- если `Angle` = 90, то вниз по OY (!),
- если 45 — то вправо-вниз...

Но уже битый час не могу понять, какие ставить условия и как разворачивать угол при столкновении со «стеной» прямоугольника, которым описана площадь, за которую точка не должна вылезти.

В каждой итерации (такт) происходит смещение точки по приведенным выше формулам и делается тест на столкновение. Извиняюсь за толстую просьбу, но я прошу дополнить (поправить?) эту секцию кода:

```
if (x <= 0)
    { Angle = ... }
else if (x >= 600)
    { Angle = ... }

if (y <= 0)
    { Angle = ... }
else if (y >= 400)
    { Angle = ... }
```

И еще у меня может быть и само движение неправильно описано, тоже поправьте пожалуйста, если так (у меня такое впечатление, что по-правильному, с увеличением угла `Angle` траектория точки должна заворачиваться против, а не по часовой — как у меня).

Comment: Вот подготовил шаблон на jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3E2jX/1/

Comment: @Bars: (там комментарии закончились) при моём выборе значение остатка -- вычет по модулю 5. У него есть приятные свойства, например: `x mod 360 == (x + 360) mod 360`. То есть, углы одинаковы т. и т. т., к. их остатки при делении на 360 равны. При традиционном для языков программирования выборе получается менее удобно. В частности, `-1 mod 360 != 359 mod 360`. И условие в `isNear` приходится писать так: `abs((b - a) mod 360) < 5`.

Comment: @Bars: вот [ещё по поводу остатков](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/05/what-s-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus.aspx) от Эрика (если вы дружите с английским).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

исправил я функцию step, обратите внимания на коментарии

```
this.step = function()
    {
    this.x = this.x + this.a * Math.cos(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);
    this.y = this.y + this.a * Math.sin(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);

    if (this.x <= 0)
        { // 
          this.angle = 180 - this.angle;
          if (this.angle < 0) this.angle += 360; // что бы угол был положительным
        }
    else if (this.x >= 600)
        { // 0 -> 180   10 -> 170
           this.angle = 180 - this.angle;
           if (this.angle < 0) this.angle += 360;
        }

    if (this.y <= 0)
        { // 270 -> 90  269 -> 91
          this.angle = 360 - this.angle;
        }
    else if (this.y >= 400)
        { // 90 -> 279   180 - 180
        this.angle = 360 - this.angle;
        }

    return this;
    };
```

или даже ещё короче

```
this.step = function()
    {
    this.x = this.x + this.a * Math.cos(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);
    this.y = this.y + this.a * Math.sin(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);

    if (this.x <= 0 | this.x >= 600)
        { // 
            this.angle = 180 - this.angle;
            if (this.angle < 0) this.angle += 360;
        }

    if (this.y <= 0 | this.y >= 400)
        { // 270 -> 90  269 -> 91
          this.angle = 360 - this.angle;
        }
    return this;
    };
```

Comment: А зачем вам нужна нормализация угла? Без неё тоже должно работать.

Comment: я вначале сделал и без нее. И оно будет работать. Но если дальше человек захочет прицепить какую то логику ещё - например искать одинаково направленные или отображать угол, или синус-косинус по таблицам считать - будут непонимания.

Поэтому лучше сразу нормализировать.

Comment: не работает почему-то http://jsfiddle.net/ReinRaus/3E2jX/3/

Comment: Ну, одинаково направленные -- это если `(b - a) mod 360 == 0` (кстати, я бы держал углы в радианах). Человек должен знать, что с углами может быть не всё так просто, иначе не избежать ошибок типа `function isClose(a, b) { return Math.abs(b - a) < 5; }` (не работает на `a = 1`, `b = 359`). А считать синус по таблицам -- моветон :)

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо большое! Особенно за 2-й вариант — это и пытался вывести.

@ReinRaus, там с закрывающей скобкой что-то не так. Вот рабочий тест: http://jsfiddle.net/3E2jX/4/

Comment: Ок. Вижу. Ставлю плюсик.

Comment: @VladD не всегда моветон, а иногда очень неплохое ускорение. Но нужно смотреть в конкретную задачу.

Comment: @KoVadim: синус и косинус на интеловской платформе считаются за одну достаточно быструю инструкцию процессора, так что тут вроде потенциала для выигрыша нет (а для проигрыша есть: нормализация, сведение к шагу таблицы, промахи кэша, если таблица большая, и т. д.). Другое дело на embedded, конечно.

Comment: В случае чего, я понял, зачем тов. @KoVadim сделал нормализацию :) Я бы, наверное, на такой тупой вопрос тоже так же ответил бы — с расчетом на идиота.

Но да, тут вопрос задачи. У меня, к примеру, угол все равно меняется в каждой итерации (это не описано в задаче, но точками во время путешествия можно управлять), так что в ф-ции `isClose` я бы брал не углы, а их остатки от деления на 360.

За замечание про радианы тоже спасибо, но мне, как человеку, не слишком близкому к геометрии, просто сложнее так отлаживать. Пойду почитаю школьные учебники по геометрии.

Comment: @Bars: для isClose брать остатки от деления углов тоже не вариант, будет неправильно на тех же значениях `a = 1`, `b = 359`. Надо брать остаток разности, на самом деле.

Comment: @Bars: причём не забудьте, что во многих языках остаток вычисляется очень неудобно: `-1 mod 5 == -1`, хотя должно было бы быть `4`.

Comment: @VladD, да, с `isClose` я напутал.

А почему `-1 mod 5` должно равняться 4? Все правильно, что 1. Здесь же операция деления, а не «вычитания до целого»